# What is wrong with my call to Firebase .setBackgroundMessageHandler?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

VS Code just put an overstrike on my call to .setBackgroundMessageHandler and says something about that it is "deprecated". But I do not understand what is wrong. What is wrong here:

```js
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
      const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
      const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.data.body,
        icon: payload.data.icon,
        locator: payload.data.locator
      };
      return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
    });
```

This code once worked, but FCM has not been working since long in this project. (Which is another problem.)

Here is the popup message from VS Code:

```
(method) firebase.messaging.Messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(callback: (payload: any) => void | Promise<any>): void
FCM directs push messages to your web page's onMessage() callback if the user currently has it open. Otherwise, it calls your callback passed into setBackgroundMessageHandler().

Your callback should return a promise that, once resolved, has shown a notification.

@param callback — The function to handle the push message.

@deprecated
onBackgroundMessage(nextOrObserver: firebase.NextFn| firebase.Observer, error?: firebase.ErrorFn,completed?: firebase.CompleteFn): firebase.Unsubscribe.
```

Answer (score 4):

From looking at the reference documentation for the [`setBackgroundMessageHandler` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#setbackgroundmessagehandler) it seems deprecated in favor of [`onBackgroundMessage`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#onbackgroundmessage):

> [Use] onBackgroundMessage(nextOrObserver: firebase.NextFn| firebase.Observer, error?: firebase.ErrorFn,completed?: firebase.CompleteFn): firebase.Unsubscribe.

Comment: If you say that it is deprecated I believe you. But may I ask you how you conclude that from the documentation? 

Comment: If you click the first link in my answer, it shows explicitly that the API is deprecated. Behind that image it then shows that you should use the `onBackgroundMessage` method instead.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it explicitly says "deprecated". But it does not explicitly say what is "deprecated" and what to use instead. Coming to that documentation I could equally well infer that `onBackgroundMessage` is deprecated. Actually I think that would be more in line with the UI-interface guidelines that Google tells us to follow.

Comment: I noticed that the other deprecated methods have the word `Use` at the start, which is missing from `setBackgroundMessageHandler`, hence inferred that it was meant to be there too. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment:  Ah, yes. The art of writing documentation. Feedback is needed.